# Time tracking-app that is counting down workingtime for projects?

Tags: project-management, time-management

I am an employee web developer for a small company. We have agreed on how much time every week I should spend on three different projects. And all working time should be time tracked.

Today we are using the app Clockify. But as many other time tracking apps, it’s only about tracking how many hours I spent on each project. Of course I can do the math and figure out how many hours I have left on each project. But it would be so much better if we could assign the daily hours every week for every project so that it then started to count down from that when I start with the time tracking.

Then if I one day work more with one project than what was assigned that day. I can cut that off another day. Or if I choose to work a night or weekend on a project then it would say somewhere how many hours I have saved to cut off from another day. It would be so much easier to work whenever I want if everything is easily presented in the app based on how much time I should spend on each project every week.

I have searched but can’t find an app that does these things.

Anyone know if that exists?